# why does restarting the Docker app improves the performance of my container (web app)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-app

I have a web app running in a Docker container on my local macOS machine. The container has multiple quite heavy (multiple GB) volumes (MySQL, WordPress core and plugins, npm stuff) which all run in delegated mode. When I start the container after a restart of the Docker app, the container is lightning fast and a webpage of my web app loads within 1 second. But when working for a while (half to whole day) with the container, the load time increases at least by a factor of 2. But when I restart the Docker app, the load time is good again.

Any ideas why is it so?
And how can I achieve the same result from the command line without restarting the Docker app?

Comment: Can you tell which container or which part of the stack is being slow?  Where is your actual data (ideally in a named volume on MacOS) and your code (should be running directly out of the image)?

Comment: Sorry, no, I have no idea which part could slow it down. 
As I wrote, the data is inside a "delegated" volume. As well ass the npm/webpack stuff and the php files. I have one container for all the parts of the app based on the Ubuntu image. Everything runs within the image. I edit only javascript (vue.js/webpack) and php (WordPress) files. MySQL volume is only for data persistence.